# PHP Contact Form not working. Getting internal server error 500

Tags: php, html, forms, email, contact-form

So I am trying to make a contact form for my website but i keep getting the internal server error 500. If anyone could look through the code and tell me if I am doing anything wrong that would be great. Thanks!

HTML name is index.html:

```
<form method="post" action="send_contact.php">
                        <p class="full-row">
                            <label for="name">Your Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
                        </p>
                        <p class="full-row">
                            <label for="email">Email:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
                        </p>
                        <p class="full-row">
                            <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject">
                        </p>
                        <p class="full-row">
                            <label for="message">Message:</label>
                            <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="6"></textarea>
                        </p>
                        <input id="submit" class="mainBtn" type="submit" name="send" value="Send Message" onClick="">   
                    </form>
```

PHP name is send_contact.php:

```
<?php
// Contact subject
$subject ="$subject"; 
// Details
$message="$detail";

// Mail of sender
$mail_from="$user_mail"; 
// From 
$header="from: $name <$mail_from>";

// Enter your email address
$to ="example@example.com";

$link = "<script>window.open('confirm.html')</script>";

$send_contact=mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

// Check, if message sent to your email 
// display message "We've recived your information"
if($send_contact){
    header('confirm.html'); 
}
else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?>
```

Comment: and the script will never work anyways, unless you're on a stone-age/brain-dead PHP that has `register_globals` turned on. `$subject = "$subject"`? Assigning something to itself is pointless, especially if that something was never defined in the first place.

Comment: If you get an "internal error", then your http server will show what error that is inside its error log file. There is little sense in _guessing_ what the issue might be if you can simply _read_ what it is by looking into that log file.

Comment: What is that meant to do: `header('confirm.html'); `? Such header does not exist or make sense. It should be `header('Location: confirm.html')`.

Comment: Nice catch @arkascha ^

Comment: header('confirm.html');    I was trying to relocate it to another page to confirm. How do I check the logs?

Comment: Sure, looks like. But you do not. Take another look at my comment above.

Comment: RTFM http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php and again, check your logs. check and display http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: [This should be getting all sorts of undefined variables notices etc...., **check for errors and display them**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: and this is invalid `from:` lowercase "f".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get variable values in PHP, use $_POST['variableName']

for example to fetch this:

```
<input type="text" name="email">
```

You will need this:

```
$email= $_POST['email']; 


<?php
// Contact subject
$subject = $_POST['subject']; 
// Details
$message=$_POST['message'];

// Mail of sender
$mail_from=$_POST['email']; 
// From 
$header="from: ".$_POST['name']." <".$_POST['email'].">";

// Enter your email address
$to ="example@example.com";

$send_contact=mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

// Check, if message sent to your email 
// display message "We've recived your information"
if($send_contact){
    header('Location: confirm.html'); 
}    
else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?>
```

Also here are additional headers to help your email going in the inbox rather than the junk box:

```
$to = "webtest@website.com";
$subject = "Test Email";
$message = "Test Email";

// normal headers
$num = md5(time()); 
$headers  = "From: Me <me@website.com>\r\n";
$headers  .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers  .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; ";
$headers  .= "boundary=".$num."\r\n";
$headers  .= "--$num\r\n";

// This two steps to help avoid spam   

$headers .= "Message-ID: <".time()." TheSystem@".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].">\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP v".phpversion()."\r\n";         

// With message

$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n";
$headers .= "".$message."\n";
$headers .= "--".$num."\n"; 


@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Cheers!

Comment: you seem to come from a C++ and/or JS background. That isn't how you concatenate. Plus, care to explain this for future visitors? ;-) no idea what this is supposed to do/represent `"from: "+$_POST['name']+" <"+$_POST['email']+">"`

Comment: Added edit, sorry, this is what happens when you work in multiple languages :p

Comment: *No problema, io capito* ;-) however Luc, it's best to add an explanation to answers, just so future visitors understand where the OP may have faulted in their code. You know, I know... some watching the question right now know, yet the OP him/herself and others may not know.

Comment: Added a bunch of things and explanations :)

Comment: Right on Luc ;-) *arrivederci!* et merci.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the form with `post` so in php you can access it like this `$name = $_POST['name']`.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the data sent through the associative array `[$_POST][1]`, like so:

```
$subject = $_POST["subject"];
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="send_contact.php">
    <p class="full-row">
        <label for="name">Your Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>
    </p>
    <p class="full-row">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email"/>
    </p>
    <p class="full-row">
        <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
        <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject"/>
    </p>
    <p class="full-row">
        <label for="message">Message:</label>
        <input type="text" name="message" id="message"/>
    </p>
    <input id="submit" class="mainBtn" type="submit" name="send" value="Send Message"/>   
</form>
```

PHP:

```
//Check if the values requested were provided
if (isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["subject"]) && isset($_POST["message"])) {
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $subject = $_POST["subject"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];

    $header = "from: $name <$email>";
    $to = "example@example.com";

    if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $header)) {
        header("Location: confirm.html");
    } else {
        echo("Error");
    }
} 
?>
```

As others have suggested, check your error logs if you're still running in to trouble.